# What is the purspose of adminConfirmSignUp command in Cognito

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-cognito

I am creating and confirming the user with

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");

let AWS_REGION = 'us-east-1';
let AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID = "My-Cognito-User-Pool-ID"
let EMAIL = "user-01@google.com";
let PASSWORD = 'Cognito1234!';

const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({  
  apiVersion: "2016-04-19",
  region: AWS_REGION
});

async function createUser() {
  
  let userData = {
    UserPoolId: AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
    Username: EMAIL,
    DesiredDeliveryMediums: ["EMAIL"],
    TemporaryPassword: PASSWORD,
    UserAttributes: [
      {
      Name: "email",
      Value: EMAIL
      },
      {
      Name: "email_verified",
      Value: "true"
      }
    ]
  };

  console.log("....userData:", userData);  

  let data = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(userData).promise();
  console.log("....data:", data);

  let confirmParams = {
    UserPoolId: AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID, 
    Username: data.User.Username, 
    ClientMetadata: {
      'SOME_KEY': 'SOME_VALUE'
    }
  };
  let result = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminConfirmSignUp(confirmParams).promise();
  console.log("....ConfirmUser:", ConfirmUser);
  return data;
}

createUser();
```

The user is created with the first command `adminCreateUser` fine. But it fails when I try to use `adminConfirmSignUp` command with the error:

```
 NotAuthorizedException: User cannot be confirmed. Current status is FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD
```

What is the purpose of the `adminConfirmSignUp` confirm command? Should I change the status of the user from FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD to something else before using the `adminConfirmSignUp` command ?

Comment: a user cannot be confirmed until they have a permanent password and `adminCreateUser` cannot be used to create a user with permanent password...i think you will need to set permanent password using adminSetUserPassword with `permanent: true` before calling adminConfirmSignUp ...

Comment: `adminSetUserPassword` with `permanent: true` sets the user status as `CONFIRMED` that causes the `adminConfirmSignUp` to throw the `NotAuthorizedException` with the message that `User cannot be confirmed. Current status is CONFIRMED`

Comment: Setting the `permanent: false` while setting the password, the user status is set to FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` which causes `adminConfirmSignUp` to raise another `NotAuthorizedException` with a message `User cannot be confirmed. Current status is FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`

Comment: What status does the `adminConfirmSignUp` command expect the user to be?

Comment: ah so `adminSetUserPassword` with `permanent: true` sets the user status as CONFIRMED? so if it is confirmed with permanent password then apparently you don't need to use `adminConfirmSignUp` after that?

Answer (score -1):

When a user signs himself up and then the Admin wants to confirm the user sign up, then you can call AdminConfirmSignUp. Flow would be:

1. User Signs up by calling SignUp API
2. Admin wants to confirm user sign up without verification so Admin calls AdminConfirmSignUP.

If you try to call AdminConfirmSignUp when user is in Force Change Password or Reset Required, then the API AdminConfirmSignUp. This is because a user will be most likely in Force change password or Reset required through an Admin initiated action (i.e. user's sign up is implicitly confirmed)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).